# Twilio Appointment Reminders

Tags: javascript, java, twilio

In my project, I am trying to implement text notifications for upcoming visits. I was looking at the Twilio tutorial (https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/appointment-reminders-node-express) for appointment reminders. I am using MySQL workbench for my database. I have a visitAPI.js file that has a function to fetch all the visits in the database (it speaks to a Java controller which speaks to the database). Is there a way to use that function (shown below) in conjunction with the tutorial code to continually get all the visits in my database, check the dates, and send a text if the appointment is in 2 days?

```
export async function fetchAll() {

  const token = localStorage.getItem('jwt_token');
  if (!token) {
    return Promise.reject(forbidden);
  }

  const init = {
    headers: {
      "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
    }
  };

  return fetch(url, init)
    .then(response => {
      if (response.status === 200) {
        return response.json();
      }
      return Promise.reject("Not 200 OK");
    });
};
```

Comment: usng a pusher app, you an do that . refer https://pusher.com/tutorials/realtime-notifications-nodejs/. Its free, in java write a daemaon, whicih will run every 1 minute and then it pushes the notification to pusher app and the subscriber will get the notificaiton

Comment: socket io, you can do for real time notifiaiton refer :https://xtreemsolution.com/blog/How-to-make-real-time-notification-system-using-socketio-and-nodejs

Comment: Are you trying to do this in the front-end of your application? If your back-end is written in Java, then you likely want to [follow the Java tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/appointment-reminders-java-spark).

Comment: I was trying to implement twilio in just the front end of my application, but I can try following the Java tutorial and putting the code in the back-end